# How to recover object with a factory binding with two arguments in kodein?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, kodein

I called a ViewModel that gets three arguments in its constructor:

```
class DetailViewModel(
    private val id: Long,
    private val tipo: String,
    private val msRepository: MSRepository) : ViewModel() {
val establishmentProfessional by lazyDeferred { 
      msRepository.getEstablishment(id, tipo)
   }
}
```

And I created a factory to build the object com DI:

```
class DetailViewModelFactory(
    private val id: Long,
    private val tipo: String,
    private val msRepository: MSRepository
    ) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return DetailViewModelFactory(id,  tipo, msRepository) as T
     }
}
```

I wrote the Factory binding as follows:`bind() from factory { id: Long, entity: String -> DetailViewModelFactory(id, entity, instance()) }`, the latter being previously reported.

However, when I try to retrieve the object, I can not spell the code correctly:

```
private var viewModelFactory: ( (Long, String) -> DetailViewModelFactory) by factory()
```

How do I retrieve the object correctly with a series of arguments?

I did not find in the documentation how to do it, because the information is insufficient.[Retrieval Direct](https://kodein.org/Kodein-DI/?6.2/core#direct-retrieval), 
[multiple argumentes](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/blob/master/doc/core.adoc#factory-binding), 
[Little documentation on multi-argument factories](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/196), 
[How can I use Kodein's direct retrieval to fetch a dependency bound as a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018569/how-can-i-use-kodeins-direct-retrieval-to-fetch-a-dependency-bound-as-a-factory/56020437#56020437)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a facotry and not an instance, use `by factory2()`.

If you want to retrieve an instance, use `by instance(arg = M(42L, "whatever"))`.

Comment: I used instance(arg=M(id, type)), but in debug inform "Lazy value not initialized yet." for the variable.